# How do I get the peak hours from my mysql database table "userlog"

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is

```
    id  username calledtime

    1   user1    01-02-2012 10:04:02
    2   user2    01-02-2012 10:12:02
    3   user1    01-02-2012 10:15:22
    5   user4    01-02-2012 11:20:02
    6   user6    01-02-2012 11:23:02
    7   user8    01-02-2012 11:34:15
    8   user7    01-02-2012 11:55:02
    9   user8    01-02-2012 15:23:02
    10  user6    01-02-2012 16:03:02
    11  user9    01-02-2012 19:43:02
```

Here the peak time is 10 - 12. because most users are called in between in 10 and 12.
How do I find out this ?

Can anyone help me out to get this

thanks

Comment: can you reconstruct your question? It's hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a group by on the hour:

```
select extract(hour from calledtime) as hr,
       count(*)
from t
group by extract(hour from calledtime)
order by 1
```

To get the peak for an hour, you would need to find the max for this.  The easiest way is:

```
select extract(hour from calledtime) as hr,
       count(*)
from t
group by extract(hour from calledtime)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

You may also want date information as well as the hour; just include that in the select and group by.